# Mesoshpere dcos opensource no authentication when going toward marathon

Tags: security, configuration, mesosphere

I have two mesospheres clusters running one on version 1.11.3 and one on 1.12.0 and i have noticed this security risk on both.

When going to the mesosphere dcos master ip-adress i need to authenticate myself using my email address before i can reach anything or start a service. But if instead go towards the martathon scheduler on port 8080. `master-ip:8080` i face no authentication at all and i can still start service or destroy service without any restrictions.

Luckily the cluster I care about is behind strict firewalls, limited amount of ports openings one of which 8080 no longer is open, solving the problem. But to me this seems like a huge security risk anyone on this network can still just go in without authenticating them self toward the cluster. where they can shutdown a running DB or kill a critical service.

Do i need to change my mesosphere dcos configuration for it to cover this or is this just a open security risk and you need your cluster to run on its own network with strict ports opened to solve this problem.

Is this a configuration error in my DCOS config?

Or is this a major security risk if running on an open network?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind marathon on 127.0.0.1 or using firewall to allow only specify ip then use nginx with http authentication basic as a proxy to marathon